# Installing Node.exe in windows 7

Tags: node.js

Currently I'm trying to learn what is node.js. I have installed node.exe in windows, don't know what is the next step to do some thing

Can you guys help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use IIS Express to run nodejs on windows. Currently on Windows you can use webmatrix from http://web.ms/

Remember that you need to use X86 of node.exe even your system is x64, since [IIS Express only ships as 32bit.](http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2011/08/developing-nodejs-applications-in.html)

If you install webmatrix and try nodejs it's automatically configure everything for you.

Remember that if you not have installed nodejs then webmatrix will install old version for you.you need to manually install node.js from it's official website.

see justin's post http://jbeckwith.com/2012/06/07/node-js-meet-webmatrix-2/

http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/how-to-use-the-nodejs-starter-template-in-webmatrix

hope this help.

Comment: Why the x86 version? any citation for this?

Comment: @MichaelPaulukonis Tomek Told me about it. Please check http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2011/08/developing-nodejs-applications-in.html and http://stackoverflow.com/a/13080610/713789

Comment: ah, IIS _EXPRESS_ (which only ships as 32 bit) - I had missed that in your original post (so I took the liberty of updating it).

Comment: am i missing something? why would you bother installing IIS (a web server) just to learn node.js, given that node.js itself can act as a standalone webserver.

Comment: @joedotnot we are IIS guys, We run everything under IIS, Even MySQL :)

Answer (score 5):

You create a js file, write your code and start the server with `node.exe path/to/file.js`. After that you could open your Browser and have a look at the program.

Here a example (`helloWorld.js`):

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('Hello World!');
}).listen(8080);

node.exe helloWorld.js
```

Open your Browser and look at `localhost:8080`

Also have a [look](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.8.8/api/) at the documentation. Additionally you find on the developer [page](http://nodejs.org/) (at the bottom), an example how to set up a webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are after learning and you are on a Win7 machine you can also host the node.exe in IIS. Perhaps you will find this guide helpful:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingAndRunningNodejsApplicationsWithinIISOnWindowsAreYouMad.aspx

Comment: IIS is used for Production and their is no requirement for installing IIS when IIS express is available for development purpose.