# iisnode can't find my 32-bit node.js installation on windows 8

Tags: node.js, iisnode

I have installed iisnode x64 and nodejs x32 though the msi installers, which resulted in node.is being installed in

```
c:\program files (x86)\nodejs
```

It has successfully installed itself in the PATH env var. Running "node" from the command line works everywhere. It does not work from IIS though, as it presents this message:

> The iisnode module is unable to start the node.exe process. Make sure
>   the node.exe executable is available at the location specified in the
>   system.webServer/iisnode/@nodeProcessCommandLine element of
>   web.config. By default node.exe is expected in one of the directories
>   listed in the PATH environment variable.

I have tried the advice from [this blog](http://www.jayway.com/2012/11/15/running-iisnode-on-windows-8-x64/) - i.e. setting the path manually in web.config. This did not help. I've also tried reinstalling node.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

To your problem I cannot find any other answer as the one mentioned in the blog you're linking. All reported issues I can find report the same answer and most people are helped. I think you're on the right track, so the only tip I can give you. Try once more and make sure you try every combination of nodeProcessCommandLine empty|C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs|C:\Program Files\nodejs in with enable/disable 32-bit applications in your application pool.

Same issue and solutions reported here:

- https://admin-ahead.com/forum/websitepanel/node-js-error!/
- http://admin-ahead.com/blog/node-js-installation-windows-2008-r2-server/
- http://www.elylucas.net/post/error-running-node-js-in-iisexpress-and-iisnode/
- https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/302
- [Error running node app in WebMatrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079199/error-running-node-app-in-webmatrix)

A part of a sample web.config (https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config
) by the author of iisnode

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <iisnode
      nodeProcessCommandLine="&quot;%programfiles%\nodejs\node.exe&quot;"
    />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Hmm, could it be the &quot;'s used in the nodeProcessCommandLine setting?

Answer (score 1):

You also need to change the path here:

%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\config\schema\iisnode_schema.xml

just delete the '(x86)' portion and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I get same error. It is because node.js cannot access to file system for writing txt file with logs. Add  folder with name *iisnote*, then right click->properties->security->users->full controlls
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfxVX.png